# ¿Cómo cambiar el diseño de un DataFrame en Python3x Pandas para agrupar todas las columnas en una sola?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un Dataframe con el formato siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
datos = {'mes':['Enero','Enero','Enero'], 
    'dia':[1,2,3],'turno':['T1','T2','T1'],
    'linea1':[1000,2000,3000], 
    'linea2':[2000,25000,4000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
```

[image: df]

En df cada linea de produccion esta en una columna, sin embargo deseo apilar los datos de tal manera que el nombre de la linea aparezca en una columna y los datos de produccion aparezcan en otra columna, tal como los mostraria el DataFrem df2.

```
datos2 = pd.DataFrame([['Enero',1,'T1',1000,2000],
                 ['Enero',2,'T2',2000,'25000'],
                 ['Enero',3,'T1',3000,'4000'] ], 
    columns = ['mes','dia','linea','turno','produccion'])
```

[image: df2]

Es importante mencionar que el dataFrame original es importado de Excel y tiene 18 lineas de produccion, es decir 18 columnas 
En la imagen df.png se muestra el DataFrame como está actualmente, en la imagen df2 se muestra el formato que debe tener.
En el siguiente enlace se puede ver el DataFrame Original[DataFrame Completo](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArAcpdafMG-bgZBz_LcpKZWYB_HOfA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, lo que buscas lo hace [`pandas.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) que en tu caso se usaría de la siguiente forma (voy a hacerlo directamente con tu dataframe completo, porque creo que la versión simplificada que has puesto tiene un error en el "resultado deseado", pues es igual al dataframe inicial sólo con las columnas reordenadas y renombradas).

```
# Esta es la url de descarga del document que has compartido en OneDrive
url = "https://kealog.bn.files.1drv.com/y4mRb2CEAfJNq2TB2xjgtB_v5NVh-ksB58GJxIk5BlsoyM8YNv7qEq-8B7u6DKOS6IU7KGOooiMjouG0TvWBIbM4H6OHt5NUpy7a-CaDuS7_yHTBKJ22Mg0NuvYapLpjogUTeVVMF3sdYT0oXcgoVU7TVzuQHmeU6xjRuAxmW26NzocJhNQMDY9mP4e-iluPpnVN76zrW0JLNCgF9QEMJgCOg/datos.csv?download&psid=1"

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(url)  # Sabías que pandas puede descargar el csv?
df.head()
```

[image: Original]

Ahora, suponiendo que las columnas que deseas conservar son "mes", "dia" y "TURNO" y que todas las demás son los nombres de las líneas:

```
# Creo una lista con los nombres de las líneas. Por no teclearlas todas
# genero en un bucle las que se llaman igual, y añado las otras
lineas = ["EAut{}".format(n) for n in range(1,13)]
lineas.extend("Granel Man1 Man2 Mezclas".split())

# Uso melt para crear el nuevo dataframe
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["mes", "dia", "TURNO"], 
                var_name="linea", value_name="produccion", 
                value_vars= lineas )
df2.head()
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Es exactamente lo que estaba buscando, me ha servido mucho, y con respecto al comentario de leer el DataFrame de un url si lo sabía. solo que yo lo estoy trabajando de forma local.